# TreeView not showing items from CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to work with `CollectionViewSource` and a `TreeView`. Here are relevant parts of the code:

XAML (partial - please let me know if more info is needed):

```
<TreeView x:Name="Projects"                               
    ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPVMs}"
</TreeView>
```

CS c'tor:

```
public CollectionViewSource FilteredPVMs { get; protected set; }
```

and then initialization:

```
 FilteredPVMs = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = PVMs };
```

then I have the filter:

```
        FilteredPVMs.View.Filter = o =>
        {
            var retVal = false;
            try
            {
                if (val != null)
                {
                    if (
                         // logic for filter...
                        )
                        retVal = true;

                    else retVal = false;
                }
                return retVal;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            return retVal;
        };

        FilteredPVMs.View.Refresh();
    }
```

I have 3 items on PVMs. When debugging, I can see that  I'm going through the filter method 3 times (for each item). For one of them I get true and for the others it's false.

I also see that FilteredPVMs.View.Count is 1: in "watch" window: ((System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView)(FilteredPVMs.View)).Count = 1

So I expect to see 1 item in the UI. However, in the UI I don't see any items. Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I never worked with CollectionViewSource  but i suspect that you will need to implement in any case the INotiFyPropertyChanged interface in your viewmodel to notify the UI (and in particular your treeview) that FilteredPVMs has changed

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the XAML (Binding FilteredPVMs.View instead of Binding FilteredPVMs) solved the problem.

```
<TreeView x:Name="Projects"                               
    ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPVMs.View}"
</TreeView
```